# Android MapBox offline download all country

Tags: android, mapbox

MapBox has a offline mode with tilesets for represent map. I need to download a whole country in my app at first start. How I can do this? Since now i downloaded small piece of country (Ukraine). And already reached the limit at 6000 tiles and 130 Mb space.

Comment: Hey, Did you check this case "if we have downloaded 5000 tiles and then trying to download 4000 tiles for different region",mapbox  will allow to download 1000 tiles and then mapbox will trow error for limit exceeded or error will trow before going to start downloading?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, either breaking up the country regions into smaller chunks and downloading them individually, i'd recommend using [this tile calculator](https://www.mapbox.com/labs/offline-estimator/) to estimate the appropriate regions. You could also restrict the zoom level to reduce tiles downloaded and preventing you from reaching the limit. Your third option would be becoming an [enterprise customer](https://www.mapbox.com/pricing).

Comment: Is there an API for the tile calculator?